# PostgreSQL: with clause returning syntax error at end of input

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

I'm trying to create a temporary table with the following code:

```
with cte_counts as 
(select entity_id, entity_name, count(distinct segment_id) as countries
from cte_geography
where cte_geography.metric_id in (2, 20, 35)
group by 1, 2
order by 3 desc)

select *
from cte_counts
```

but I get the error:
**ERROR: syntax error at end of input Position: 529**

I've retyped it and I can't spot what's wrong. Without ***with***, the code works fine:

```
select entity_id, entity_name, count(distinct segment_id)
from cte_geography
where cte_geography.metric_id in (2, 20, 35)
group by 1, 2
order by 3 desc
```

NOTE: performing this on Metabase.

Comment: Well, a CTE can not exist by itself, it needs a statement after the closing `)` bracket.

Comment: I've edited the question. When using select to visualise all the data it returns the same error.

Comment: As @Stefanov.sm said you need to do something like:`...order by 3 desc) select * from cte_counts`.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver. I've edited the question. The error persists...

Comment: There can't be a line between the `WITH()` and the `SELECT`.

Comment: The code [works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fde3561622f516df6d1477d7811da34f)

Comment: Sorry there can be, but I'm guessing in your case there is some hidden character causing an issue.

Comment: Try removing the order by.

Comment: Position 529. It's that character position? You've got something else in your console.

Comment: Apart from this, I have commented code.

Comment: Searching the Postgres source I can not find that error message. That leads me to believe it is coming from the client you are running the query in. What is the client and its version? Add answer as update to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when creating a CTE. I was getting a syntax error at the end ). I tried what @AdrianKlaver suggested and added; ) Select * From CTE. It worked perfectly after that.